# Update UILabel dynamically with text entering in UITextView?

Tags: ios, uilabel, uitextview

I have two view controllers and I want to update my `UILabel` at the same time when I am writing in `UITextView`... For example if I am writing some text in `UITextView`, it should appear simultaneously in `UILabel` without clicking any button or something like that... It should be updated dynamically...
Thanx,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code ,set delegate for your textview

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{

    lbl.text=textView.text;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... By the way 
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
worked  better in my case :)